# Regex in perl/sed replacement not matching whitespace/characters

Tags: regex, perl

Given [this](http://static.arounds.org/file.html) file, I'm trying to do a super primitive `sed` or `perl` replacement of a footer.

Typically I use DOM to parse HTML files but so far I've had no issues due to the primitive HTML files I'm dealing with ( time matters ) using sed/perl.

All I need is to replace the `<div id="footer">` which contains whitespace, an element that has another element, and the closing `</div>` with `<?php include 'footer.php';?>`.

For some reason I can't even get this pattern to match up until the `<div id="stupid">`. I know there are whitespace characters so i used `\s*`:

```
perl -pe 's|<div id="footer">.*\s*.*\s*|<?php include INC_PATH . 'includes/footer.php'; ?>|' file.html | less
```

But that only matches the first line. The replacement looks like this:

```
<?php include INC_PATH . includes/footer.php; ?> 
                   <div id="stupid"><img src="file.gif" width="206" height="252"></div>

               </div>
```

Am I forgetting something simple, or should I specify some sort of flag to deal with a multiline match?

`perl -v` is 5.14.2 and I'm only using the `pe` flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `-0777`, which will force perl to read the entire file at once.

```
perl -0777 -n -e 's|something|else|g' file
```

Also, your strategy of doing `.*\s*.*\s*` is pretty fragile. It'll match e.g. `<div id="foo"`, which is just a fragment...

Comment: `perl -0777 -i -pe 's|<div id="footer">.*\s*.*\s*|<?php include INC_PATH . 'includes/footer.php'; ?>|g' file.html` worked. thanks! time to adjust my regex to be more specific, it was primitive for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting that almost all regex parsing works on a line-by-line basis?

I've always had to use `tr` to convert the newlines into some other character, and then back again after the regex.

Just found this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17947
You need to tell the regex engine to treat your scalar as a multiline string with the /m option; otherwise it won't attempt to match across newlines.

Comment: Isn't there some flag I can feed like `m` which does multiline matching? I've been using rubular.com often, I suppose it has that by default. The problem is probably that perl's regex engine isn't the same as the JS/ruby ones.

Comment: Yeah, you win on that one; I found it slightly after you posted suggesting it.  I learned something useful :)

Comment: The `m` option is the `multiline` modifier, it makes the `^` and `$` anchors match on the start and the end of a line. What you mean is `s` the `singleline` modifier (single line because it treats the whole string as one line), it makes the `.` matches newline characters. But this is not the problem here, since the `\s` is here to match the newlines, what would work, if it would see the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p
```

is working on the file on a line by line basis [see perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html)

that means your regex will never see all lines to match, it will only match when it gets the line that starts with "`<div id="footer">`" and on the following lines it will not match anymore.

Comment: That link seems useful. It is a bit dated though. ( i.e. `-E` isn't mentioned because it didn't exist in 2004 )